# Get absolute path on host for container PID's executable

Tags: bash, docker, proc

**Context:**

- CentOS 7 host
- Ubuntu container
- Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
```

**Observation:**

Building and running the above container, a new bash process will be launched on the CentOS host in the appropriate namespaces.

This will not be an instance of `/bin/bash` from the host, but will instead be an instance of the bash executable inside the mounted container image.

E.G. the process running `/bin/bash` in the container is really running `/var/lib/docker/overlay2/<hash>/merged/bin/bash` on the host?

**My question:**

From the host, how can I obtain the absolute path to the executable for a given host PID of a container process?

**Investigation:**

I currently map PID-to-executable-absolute-path by piecing it together from:

- host PID found in `lsns` or `ps`
- host `df` output like `/var/lib/docker/overlay2/<hash>/`

  - `<hash>` grabbed from host `/proc/<PID>/task/<PID>/mounts`
  - usually just observe changes in `df` when launching the container though...
- container ENTRYPOINT or container `/proc/1/exe`

This works when there are very few container processes in play, allowing manual tracking of the above.

Is there is a way to automate it? I am aware `docker container inspect` could yield the mounted `<hash>` a little easier.

The process [documented here](https://blog.stangroome.com/2017/12/05/inspecting-docker-container-processes-from-the-host/) may work when Docker uses `aufs` but with `overlay2` it only prints the container path for me, not the absolute host one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51553395 looks related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merged directory can be easily extracted with that command:
`mergeddir=$(docker inspect container_name | grep merged | cut -f 4 -d '"')`

Next, concatenate `$mergeddir` with executable path to get what you want.